# Beginner trying to make a Hangman Program in C#

Tags: c#

Making a hangman game how can I compare my userInput to the given string/char in the word and then how i can somehow record the position of this correct char to display back to the user.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {  
       /*   static int ResponseCorrect() 
            {
               Random rnd = new Random();
               int response = rnd.Next(1, 4); 

               switch (response)
               {
                   case 1:
                       RandWord = "Robot";
                       break;

                   case 2:
                       RandWord = "Fish";
                       break;

                   case 3:
                       RandWord = "James";
                       break;

                   case 4:
                       RandWord = "Chocolate";
                       break;
               }

               return response;
           }*/

       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
          string value = "Robot";
          int userInput = 0;
          string inData = "";
          string inData2 = "";
          char myletter = 'd';
          bool letterinWord = false;

          Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Hangman, Please select a number between 1 and 4 for your number!");
          inData = Console.ReadLine();
          userInput = Convert.ToInt32(inData);

          Console.WriteLine("This is your first guess, enter a letter");
          inData2 = Console.ReadLine();
          myletter = Convert.ToChar(inData2);

          char[] array = value.ToCharArray();

          for (int counter = 0; counter < array.Length; counter++)
          {
             char letter = array[counter];
             if (myletter == letter)
             {
                letterinWord = true;
             }
          }

          if (letterinWord == true)
             Console.WriteLine("Congratulations");
          else
             Console.WriteLine("u suck");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to make your question more specific it is to general at the moment

Comment: Please remove unnecessary text and code so we can quickly look at the actual issue. You don't have to give us an introduction to yourself, just the problem and a clear description of your attempts, their results and their expected outcomes will suffice.

Comment: sorry about that, this is my first post, i think someone edited for me, thank you to whoever did that.

Comment: @user3084866 I removed a lot of unessasary text from your question. Try to make your questions shorter and stick to the point. This will increase your chances of someone taking time to help you

Comment: @user, please also explain which lines of code are relevent for the problems you are having.  For example, when you ask, "how can I compare my userInput to the given string/char?", you should show the two or three lines of code where you are collecting the user input.  Then when you ask, "how i can somehow record the position of this correct char to display back to the user?", you should explain what "position" you are referring to, and where you currently have code that is trying to display any input (correct or otherwise) at all.

Comment: @user3084866, I tried helping your explain the different things you may need to understand to get this working, I did so without spoon-feeding you too much, if you have any problems understanding my answer, let me know and I will try to revise it. Remember for the future, it is much easier if you ask a simple short question that is easy to answer and understand. Also note that the code I explain may or may not work out of the box, you may need to try and come up with some answers yourself along the way! Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I compare my userInput to the given string/char in the word

A string is essentially a collection of characters, also known as an `array` of `chars`.

That means that you could do something like this to get a certain `index` (positions) from within a collection of `chars` (a string):

```
var someWord = "Filip Ekberg";
Console.WriteLine(someWord[0]);
```

This will print the following to your console:

> F

Because we asked for the first position in our array.

You just want to ask for one character at a time, so let us say that you expect the user to write: `F` and then press `Enter`. Now, you just want to use the `F`, right? So you could do:

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
var firstCharacter = input[0];

if(firstCharacter == someWord[0]) { /* Yay! /* }
```

Notice the "hardcoded" `0` for the `someWord` index? Those aren't really what we want, right? So we'd like to do something like the following:

1. Ask for user input as long as we are "alive". Possibly have a counter inside a `while(true)` that you check that against
2. Run a for loop that checks each character in the `someWord` array:

   `for(var i = 0; i < someWord.Length; i++) { /* Now we can use someWord[i] /* }`
3. If there was no occurrence of the character you entered when you check that in the for loop, reduce the lives by one!